# Name for the art style with wacky space alien illustrations like on the Area 51 SE site?

Tags: drawing, illustration, style, style-identification

What is the name of the art style with wacky space alien characters? I've seen the style in many places over time but a good example which I can provide is the illustrations in the [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site. Here are some examples:

[image: UFO and moon]
[image: Planet landscape with space vehicles]
[image: Aliens saying bye to a departing rocket ship]

Comment: I assume you mean more specific than "cartoon"?

Comment: I don't know what style it is exactly but it reminds me of Hanna Barbera cartoons cartoons, such as the Flinstones and the Jetsons. May be worth checking that out? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanna-Barbera

Comment: It reminded me of the [Dexter's Lab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dexter%27s_Lab) and [Johnny Bravo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnny_Bravo) style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mid-Century Modern style graphics

Answer (score 3):

'[Retro 60s animation](https://www.google.com/search?q=retro%2050s%20cartoon&client=firefox-a&hs=FOl&rls=org.mozilla:nl:official&channel=sb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=G9cSVMfuAoe1PLahgagP&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1358&bih=828#rls=org.mozilla:nl:official&channel=sb&tbm=isch&q=retro%2060s%20animation)' and '[Retro 50s animation](https://www.google.com/search?q=retro%2050s%20cartoon&client=firefox-a&hs=FOl&rls=org.mozilla:nl:official&channel=sb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=G9cSVMfuAoe1PLahgagP&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1358&bih=828#rls=org.mozilla:nl:official&channel=sb&tbm=isch&q=retro%2050s%20animation)' go a long way.